# Is the speed of the VPN related to the ISP?

Tags: networking, vpn, dns, cloudflare

Note that the ISP I mentioned is not the ISP of VPN (such as cloudflare, windscribe), but the ISP of home/school WIFI (it can also be 4/5G)
I'm in China, I use vpn like cloudflare warp to access foreign websites, warp works fine on school network, but it's very slow on home network. My school network and home network are from different ISPs, I wonder why vpn will show such an extreme gap in different network environments

Answer (score 0):

Internet speeds will always be as slow as the slowest connection.

If at home, your internet speed is 100 mbit, but your wifi is only 20 mbit, your  speed will only be 20 mbit.

If at school, they have 1 gigabit internet and their wifi reaches 500mbit, your speed will be 500 mbit. If the VPN limits this to 200mbit, then your speed will still be 200 mbit, instead of just 20 mbit.

Small note: Some ISP's will limit the speed of a VPN, and Windows 11 has an update that seriously breaks VPN speeds. If at school you use a different computer than at home, you may have this windows update installed.

So TL;DR: Your speed is determined by whatever is the slowest component in the entire chain. From VPN performance, to ISP performance, to local network performance.